# Application crashes when executing NSBatchDeleteRequest with "Unknown Command Type <NSBatchDeleteRequest,..>"

Tags: swift, macos, core-data

I'm writing an OS X application, and it needs to be able to delete all "SongEntity" instances held in its Core Data store. 
However, when I try to execute an NSBatchDeleteRequest, my application crashes, with the following console-output (excerpt):

> Unknown command type  (entity: SongEntity; predicate:
>   ((null)); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type:
>   NSManagedObjectIDResultType; ) >

Here's my implementation:

```
func clearStore()
{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SongEntity")
    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)

    do
    {
        try managedObjectContext.executeRequest(deleteRequest)
    }
    catch
    {
        fatalError("Not able to perform operation: \(error)")
    }
    managedObjectContext.reset()
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

**EDIT:**
It turns out that this issue is related to the chosen store-type: 
From class `NSBatchDeleteRequest`:

```
//  May not be supported by all store types.
```

I tried changing the store-type from `NSXMLStoreType` (the macOS template default) to `NSSQLiteStoreType` and now it works.

Comment: "under certain circumstances"? – Note hat NSBatchDeleteRequest requires iOS 9.

Comment: I deleted that wording (thanks). So NSBatchDeleteRequest is not available on OS X...? From [El Capitan Release Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_11.html) I understand, that NSBatchDeleteRequest _is_ supported on El Capitan

Comment: I apologize, I had overlooked the [osx] tag. I don't know if it is available on OS X (and since when).

Answer (score 20):

I ran into this problem too using NSInMemoryStoreType on my persistent store. It turns out that not all store types support batch deletes, so I had to switch to using a fetch request and simply iterating over the managed objects and removing them one by one.

Answer (score 3):

`NSBatchDeleteRequest` is executed on the persistent store coordinator, not the managed object context.

```
try persistentStoreCoordinator.executeFetchRequest(
    batchDeleteRequest, withContext:context
)
```

Comment: for OS X it is just `executeRequest` without fetch. However I am having the described issue, even though I am executing the request on the persistentStoreCoordinator. Any ideas? :/

Comment: You are referring to Swift 3. This is an older answer.

Comment: Ah Sorry. Thought it was an iOS / Mac difference, not Swift 2 / Swift 3.